# Cant send file in Laravel using ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel, file

I'm trying to send a file to my controller using and ajax call. I went through many answers and i came up with this code.

```
 $('#btn_stock_create').on('click',function(){
    var create_stock_type = $('#create_stock_type').val();
    var create_tag_no = $('#create_tag_no').val();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", $("#create_image")[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({                    
        url: '/stocks/create',
        type: 'POST',     
        data: {
             _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
             create_stock_type:create_stock_type,
             create_tag_no:create_tag_no,
             create_image:formData,
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function (data) { 
           if (data.result == 1) {
                table.ajax.reload();
                swal({
                    title: data.status,
                    text:  data.message,   
                    icon:   "success",
                });
                $('#createModal').modal('hide');
                $('#createModal').find('form').trigger('reset');
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

My form is inside a bootstrap-modal. My form is given below:

```
   <form id="create_stock_form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="form-group">
         .... (Rest of the inputs)
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label for="create_image" class="col-md-12 control-label" >Stock Image</label>
              <div class="col-md-12">
               <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="create_image">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

So when the ajax is called Handler Exception is shown.

C:..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php.

Can anyone please tell me why this happens. I just cant seem to send the file to controller using my ajax function. Or is there any other solution to this.
Please help me.

Comment: The exception handler being called means you have an exception of some sort. The details of that exception should be available if you look at the HTTP response in your browser's network console (if `APP_DEBUG` is set to true) or in the logs.

Comment: 419 unknown status this is shown in console.

Comment: You're probably not sending the CSRF token properly. Is `CSRF_TOKEN` set to the value of the CSRF token somewhere? I'm not seeing its definition in your code.

Comment: yes it is already set ``var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');``

Comment: Take a look at the network request and see if it's sending the correct value.

Comment: Normally when we send via ajax, it will shows Form Data. But in my network it doesnt show Form Data.
Instead its showing: Request Payload [Object] [object]

Comment: Yeah. nothing is sent via call i guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187397/discussion-between-lano-angel-and-ceejayoz).

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this help**

add accept attribute on your input

`<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="create_image" accept="image/*>`

**Ajax submit request**

```
$('#btn_stock_create').on('click',function(){
   var formData = new FormData($('#create_stock_form').find('#create_image')[0]);
 $.ajax({                    
    url: '/stocks/create',
    type: 'POST',     
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',                   
    success: function (data) { 
       if (data.result == 1) {
            table.ajax.reload();
            swal({
                title: data.status,
                text:  data.message,   
                icon:   "success",
            });
            $('#createModal').modal('hide');
            $('#createModal').find('form').trigger('reset');
        }
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Ok i will try this.